# Why do Apache Tomcat versions start with version 3?

Tags: tomcat

According to the Apache Tomcat [release page](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) Tomcat 3.0 was the initial release of Tomcat:

> **Apache Tomcat 3.0.x.** Initial Apache Tomcat release.

What happened to Tomcat version 1.x and 2.x?

Comment: Actually - if you review the answer provided (and accepted - which makes a change on serverfault) you'll see that it _didn't_ solicit any debate or argument and the answer was supported by facts and references. Therefore calling this a non-constructive question would be wrong (IMHO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has never been a Tomcat version 1.x or 2.x. Tomcat came to life as a merger between Apache JServ (which implemented the Servlet Spec 2.0 in its last version) and Sun's reference implementation of the Servlet Spec 2.1. The first release of Apache Tomcat was then 3.0 - see also http://tomcat.apache.org/heritage.html.